# A "cheating" quine

Tags: code-golf, quine

Long-time lurker, first-time poster. So here goes.

In the Wikipedia page for [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29#.22Cheating.22_quines), it says that "a quine is considered to be 'cheating' if it looks at its own source code." Your task is to make one of these "cheating quines" that reads its own source code.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes - *in each language* - wins. This means that a 5-byte Pyth script would not beat a 21-byte Python script - but a 15-byte Python script would.

You must use file I/O to read the source code, so the following JavaScript code, taken from the official Wikipedia page, is invalid:

```
function a() {
    document.write(a, "a()");
}
a()
```

It must access the source code of the file *on disk*.

**You are not allowed to specify the file name. You must make it detect the filename itself.**

Everyone clear? Go!

Comment: Is it allowed to specify the name of the file that the program is run in? How should that be scored?

Comment: Is a trailing newlines not present in the original file allowed?

Comment: @isaacg IMHO That's not a quine, since it is not the source code.

Comment: You should state a requirement that it determine the actual filename instead of assuming a hard-coded string for the source location.

Comment: I agree with @feersum though, that requiring a specific file name makes this challenge way to trivial.

Comment: @isaacg No, it isn't. I'll add that to the OP

Comment: Can we assume that (for compiled languages) the source code is in the same folder (i.e. we can just add ".cpp" or ".hs" to arg[0] to get the source).

Comment: @HEGX64 Sure, that makes sense.

Comment: APL uses a workspace to store and execute code. May I read the program code from the workspace? The program will not contain its own name.

Comment: @Adám I'm not sure how this workspace thing works, but what I'm going for is reading the program code from the filesystem. If it does that, great.

Comment: @TheInitializer [The workspace](http://aplwiki.com/LearnApl/AplWorkspace) is already fully loaded into memory before the command is given to a program to run. In that sense, the workspace is APL's virtual "file" system.

Comment: @Adám It seems fine I guess.

Comment: The challenge could have attracted by far more creative solutions without this restriction to source file reading from disk. All languages without disk access are excluded, for example. And all clever tricks on how to break some interpreter restriction ...

Comment: @Philippos Probably true, but to be fair I did write this problem when I was 13

Comment: For a 13 year old, this is quite a nice challenge, I admit. (-:

Answer (score 66):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 4 bytes

```sh
<$0
```

The Z shell has feline functionalities built in. The fourth character is a linefeed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/zsh#@2@jYsD1/z8A)

The code does not depend in any way on the file name; it works even if the file name contains special character, such as spaces or newlines.

#### Test run

```
$ cat "my quine.sh"
<$0
$ zsh "my quine.sh" 
<$0
$ diff -s <(zsh "my quine.sh") <(cat "my quine.sh")
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

Comment: `feline functionalities` :)

Answer (score 49):

## Bash, 6 bytes

```
cat $0
```

Basically.

Comment: Why was this down voted? It does exactly what the program asked for.

Comment: Doesn't cat append a trailing newline? So this is 7 bytes?

Comment: It does not print a newline.

Comment: `cat` does not append a newline (at least on my system).

Comment: @isaacg `cat` prints the content of the supplied file byte per byte.

Comment: Note that #!cat in a file also works for a cheating quine. But not when the file is called with bash.

Comment: @LukStorms That's a good point. I wonder if that is valid...

Comment: Not sure. It does feel like a bigger cheat.

Comment: @LukStorms it would mean that I could beat Pyth though (mwahahaha). I'll ask chat what they think

Comment: @LukStorms But wouldn't this be a `cat` solution then, instead of a `bash` solution? And cat does not really qualify as programming language

Comment: @fschmengler I'd say it's a sh solution, and cat is just one of many possible standard system commands in a sh shebang.

Comment: @Sparr: On my system, #! works even if sh doesn't exist (but you have to use the full path).

Comment: @Joshua sure, because #! also exists in whatever shell you're using to run the script. It's not *just* a sh directive.

Comment: @Sparr: I discovered it's in the kernel on my system.

Comment: Will this work if the file is named `-e` ?

Comment: @fschmengler & Joshua.  Now that I readup on the shebang. It seems when it's in a script on a unix-like system it's called by the program loader of the system. So if you run a script with only a she-banged line then you can't call it a bash script.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have no idea how you would run a shell script named this from the command line. You can't escape the dash with a backslash.

Comment: If the file name starts with a dash, you'd have to call the script as `bash ./-e`, which will still work, since this is the argument that gets passed to Bash. (Without quotes, `$0` won't handles whitespace in the file name though.)

Comment: @LukStorms `#!cat` only works if your current directory is `/bin`. I wonder whether a solution is allowed to make such requirements.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If the file is named `-e` and executed like this `execl("-e", "-e", NULL);`, then `bash` will in fact think `-e` is an option rather than a file name. But if the script is invoked from a `bash` shell, I am not sure you can get `bash` to invoke the script without passing a path to the file.

Comment: @kasperd Also depends on your $PATH variable? PATH normally has /usr/bin, which includes cat.

Comment: @LukStorms Scanning the `PATH` is done by user mode library code, but `#!` is handled by the kernel and doesn't take `PATH` into account. If you want a `#!` line to use `PATH` it is usually done by taking advantage of an intermediate program like for example `#!/usr/bin/env python`, but that's not very useful for code golf.

Comment: @kasperd Ok. I had only tested it in cygwin, which doesn't have a problem with it. But on a linux it's indeed a problem. Not that it matters, it was already discussed that it wouldn't count as a bash script.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Naming the file "-e" works fine on bash, zsh and sh for me.

Comment: Not pure `bash`, it needs some other executable, namely `cat`, present and findable in the `$PATH`. However, `bash` does the interpretation logic, and if `cat` is present, it can be assumed as a command available to `bash`.

Comment: @GolarRamblar Most bash submissions assume coreutils are available.

Comment: naming the file `-e` works for me on msys2

Comment: tried to name the file `-e` and execute it using `(bash|sh|zsh) -- -e` and it failed with all of them

Answer (score 38):

## UNIX executable loader, 10 bytes

```
#!/bin/cat
```

If you don't care about spam on standard error, you can make it one byte shorter:

```
#!/bin/dd
```

Comment: I like this.  Not sure if it qualifies as a "language," though.

Comment: Perhaps cheating a bit, but couldn't you rename your bin folder and the cat program to shorten the path?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you **do** btw. I'm suggesting you **could**

Comment: @Kevin The "language" (that is, interpreter) is `cat`. And I guess if you want to be very specific, a `cat` program simply prints itself, and is compatible with every file format in existence :)

Comment: @JamesWebster `sudo install /bin/cat /c`. Y'know, just in case `/bin` isn't on the root filesystem. Gotta have that `cat` in singleuser…

Comment: @l0b0: The "language" here is not `cat`. The interpreter we play with here is within the kernel (e.g., Linux), which reads the first two bytes (magic bytes) of a file given to it in order to execute it, and if it finds them to be `#!`, it continues to read the line to get a path of another executable which it will then execute, passing the file's path as an argument to it. The interpreter here is _not_ `cat`, but part of the kernel. `cat` is just invoked after the kernel interpreted the first line, and then just does the file I/O. Here it is the same as with the bash-answer (`cat $0`) above.

Comment: *BSD needs a newline.

Answer (score 25):

## C, 52

```
s[99];main(){read(open(__FILE__,0),s,99);printf(s);}
```

Of course, this reads the source code and not the compiled program - I assume that's within spec.

Comment: You could use `printf` instead of `puts` to avoid a trailing newline.

Comment: @feersum yes, good catch

Comment: @downvoter ... you know ... just curious...

Comment: @DigitalTrauma It's because of your avatar, of course

Comment: Actually, `puts` can be used, you just need to `read` fewer characters.

Comment: You are assuming `s` is initialized with `NUL` characters. Is that guaranteed to be the case?

Comment: @kasperd [Yes, guaranteed by C89](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015656/are-global-variables-always-initalized-to-zero-in-c)

Comment: Save two bytes: `s[50];main(){read(open(__FILE__,0),s,50);puts(s);}` by reading only 50 characters you skip the possible newline and can use `puts` instead of `printf`.

Comment: If you don't want to edit that in, can I post it as a new answer?

Comment: @MDXF Normally such a trivial difference doesn't warrant a new answer, so I wouldn't encourage it.  I can't stop you though ;-).  FWIW, if you use `puts()` then the extra newline will mean your source must also end in a newline, making it 51 bytes.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Still a byte less... :D

Answer (score 23):

## [Vyxal 2.4.0](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.4.0), 50 bytes

```
`\");VY_print(chr(96)+code.split('\n')[3][15:-4])#
```

Vyxal doesn't have a way to read files, but in v2.4.0 and prior, there was an ACE exploit that allowed for arbitrary python to be executed.

---

#### The ACE:

Vyxal is a transpiled language, meaning that every command in a program is converted to some python code, and then all of the python code is combined together and executed.

When pushing a string, all that was done to the string in transpilation was changing `"` to `\\\"`, then appending it to the stack. This meant that a string `\"); #` would become `\\");#`. On its own, this means nothing, but when considered in the transpiled code, it is much more useful.

When viewing the transpiled code (which you can do for any Vyxal program using the `c` flag), you can see that the snippet `` `\\"); # `` is transpiled to the following python code:

```
stack.append("\\"); #\n")
```

Instead of pushing the string that we told it to, it simply pushed `\`, followed by a comment. In theory, we could put any python code between the `;` and the `#`, which is what we do in this program.

---

#### The program:

In this program, the payload (the python code that we actually care about) is the following:

```
VY_print(chr(96)+code.split('\n')[3][15:-4])
```

This has several parts to it, so lets pick it apart bit by bit.

`VY_print` is the printing function that is defined internally in Vyxal. I used this function instead of `print` because it disables the implicit output that Vyxal normally has. This prints the final string, which will hopefully be the same as the program.

When the program is transpiled, the transpiled code is saved in the `code` variable. This variable is used in the program to read the source code, which makes this a cheating quine.

However, the `code` variable also contains a header that initializes a few variables, such as the stack. To combat this, we `split` the code on newlines and get only the fourth line, which is where our code is.

Unfortunately, this line also has the `stack.append...`, and the comment at the end, neither of which are part of our quine. Because of this, we need to take only the 16th through 5th-to-last characters in the string, which we do with `[15:-4]`.

Finally, our code has a backtick at the beginning to start the string, so we add one to the beginning of the output with `chr(96)`, since the ASCII value of `` ` `` is 96.

Comment: Wooooo crappy programming ftw!

Answer (score 14):

### Perl, 15 bytes

```pl
open 0;print<0>
```

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @[ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31388/thissuitisblacknot)!

Comment: You can save 3 bytes with `open 0;print<0>`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I was sure there was a shorter way to do it, but I couldn't for the life of my work it out... Using `0` assumes `$0` then?

Comment: Yep. See `perldoc -f open`: "As a shortcut a one-argument call takes the filename from the global scalar variable of the same name as the filehandle: `$ARTICLE = 100; open(ARTICLE) or die "Can't find article $ARTICLE: $!\n";`"

Answer (score 13):

## PHP, 21 Bytes

```
<?=file(__FILE__)[0];
```

`file` reads a file line by line into an array and the file only has one line. This saves a byte in comparison to `readfile(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Notice that this only works from PHP5.4 and up, which was the first version to support array de-referentiation. But other than that, quite a nice answer!

Comment: `readfile` is also 21: `<?readfile(__FILE__);`.

Comment: Right, it doesn't need `<?=`

Answer (score 13):

## Perl 6, 20 bytes

```
print slurp $?FILE
```

I haven't worked with Perl 6 very long so I'm not sure if there are any tricks to make this shorter.

Comment: can you remove the second space?

Comment: @Eevee nope, it gets angry

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2, 32 bytes

There's a newline at the end of the file.

```
print open(__file__).readline()
```

## Python 3, 33 bytes

There's a newline at the end of the file.

```
print(open(__file__).readline())
```

Thanks to [feersum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30688/feersum) for catching a problem and supplying `__file__`, [Loovjo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34543/loovjo) for a new approach to the Python 2 solution that saved 17 bytes, and [Skyler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45727/skyler) for a solution that saved yet another byte and worked in both Python 2 and 3 (pending `print` being a function in Python 3)!

[Doc link for `readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: This would also save 2 bytes in python3 because you could discard the `end` parameter.

Comment: @Skyler You're absolutely correct.

Comment: How does this work in Python 3, which needs parens for `print`?

Comment: Python 3 should be `print(open(__file__).readline())` followed by a newline.

Comment: Your Python 3 example says Python 2 rather than Python 3

Comment: @TheInitializer fixed, thanks

Comment: You can use `print(open(__file__).read(30))` to save 3 Bytes

Comment: @nTerior only two; `readline` becomes `read`, and `30` gets added. That is the same idea as xsot's answer, but applied to 3.x where it works just as well. The number used is one less than the file length (assuming single-character newlines) because the last character (the newline) will come from `print`'s default formatting.

Answer (score 12):

## osascript (AppleScript from the command line), <s>40</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
(read path to me)'s paragraph 1
```

Executing on a file called a with `osascript a`.

Gets the first paragraph (line) of the file and prints it to STDOUT with a trailing newline, therefore the newline in the code.

Comment: See my edit to the OP

Comment: Working on getting it to work.

Comment: `read path to me` seems to work for me.  El Cap.

Comment: Didn't see this, but this is the way I ended up doing it. :P Thanks, @DigitalTrauma. EDIT: trailing newlines must be considered, so you add the newline and use paragraphs 1.

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2.7, 30 bytes

```
print open(__file__).read(29)
```

Edit: Just to be clear, the code above is supposed to have a newline at the end as the 30th byte. I'm not familiar with markdown enough to figure out how to display it in the code block.

I'm using the same trick here as the one in my C submission. This reads the whole source file excluding the trailing newline to account for the additional newline which `print` will append to the output.

Comment: Does this run into the same problem with the trailing newline that the other submission did?

Comment: No. There's supposed to be a trailing newline that makes the 30th byte in the source code but I can't get it to display in the code block. My submission works because it reads the first 29 bytes of the source code so that the newline from `print` won't be extraneous.

Comment: That's not what the comma does. It appends a space instead of a newline.

Comment: could use ␤ to indicate a semantically-important newline

Answer (score 11):

## Batch, <del>9</del> 8 Bytes

```
@type %0
```

Saved a byte thanks to @Joshua

Comment: You can save a byte by eliminating the trailing %.

Answer (score 9):

## AutoIt, 34 bytes

Outputs itself to the clipboard:

```
ClipPut(FileRead(@ScriptFullPath))
```

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, 14

```
$>.<<IO.read$0
```

Comment: Nice use of `.` to avoid parentheses

Answer (score 8):

## Go, <s>111</s> 105 bytes

```
package main
import("io"
."os"
."runtime")
func main(){_,p,_,_:=Caller(0)
f,_:=Open(p)
io.Copy(Stdout,f)}
```

My first code-golf in Go – just a few tricks you can use here I guess.

Comment: There is already an answer in Go - does this use the same method?

Comment: @VoteToClose: I realise it, I was inspired by the other one indeed, but used package renaming here (cheap trick) as well as different technique for opening and piping file to stdout. Saved me a massive 22 bytes ;-)

Comment: The method is actually a bit different, good one!

Answer (score 7):

## C, 49 bytes

```
s[];main(){read(open(__FILE__,0),s,48);puts(s);}
```

Edit: To clarify, the 49th byte is a newline.

This reads the source code minus the newline at the end to account for the newline which `puts` will append to the end of the output.

Comment: This code invokes undefined behavior twice.

Comment: Well, this is code golf. My code produces the desired output so it's a valid submission.

Comment: @xsot In that case, you should probably list the compiler version + options; otherwise this might not be verifiable.

Comment: It should work for most versions of gcc without any  compilation option.

Comment: You'll also have to specify the filesystem it's on in this case. Some filesystems may not ensure the first read() call returns all 48 bytes (a successful read will read between 1 byte and the number of bytes passed).

Comment: If having undefined behavior is permitted as long as you can have some compiler that produces the desired output on some machine during some phase of the moon, then I propose int main(void) { *0; } as a solution.  After all, the standard would permit an implementation that compiles that into a program that solves the problem.  I'd be fine with using implementation-dependent behavior as long as you specify the compiler, but with undefined behavior, you can't even guarantee that you wouldn't get ten different answers if you ran that ten times in a row on the same machine.

Comment: @Ray Sure, you could write a compiler that makes `int main(void) { *0; }` as a solution, but **1** you'd have to mark solutions using it as noncompeting 'cause it'd be newer than the challenge; **2** you'd be downvoted into oblivion; **3** it's really boring.

Comment: @MDXF I wasn't seriously suggesting that we write that solution.  I was arguing against allowing undefined behavior. `int main() {*0;}` *might* work even on existing compilers, since it contains undefined behavior. Similarly, xsot's solution *might* work on existing compilers, since it contains undefined behavior. Neither one is guaranteed to solve the problem. (Although xsot's is admittedly more *likely* to do so, it might just as easily crash). My actual argument is that we should permit solutions that depend on implementation-dependent or unspecified behavior, but not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ray So it would've been better practice if he'd included in the header **(gcc)** or **(clang)** or **(tcc)**, but the truth is, most smart compilers these days will perform the same for some types of undefined behavior. This is one.

Comment: @MDXF That would be useful if it was implementation-dependent or unspecified behavior.  But if it's undefined, it might work one run and crash the next, even with the same compiler.  He's writing to an array with no memory allocated to it.  This isn't a purely theoretical situation; that might very well crash depending on what lives in that memory.  (Though the fact that it's declared in file scope makes it a bit less likely.)

Answer (score 7):

## PowerShell, <strike>39</strike> <strike>36</strike> <strike>31</strike> 25 Bytes

About as tight as I can get it:

<strike>`gc $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | oh`</strike>

Backed by popular demand this has been changed to:

```
gc $PSCommandPath|echo -n
```

prints to <strike>host shell</strike> current standard output.

Comment: `gc $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` is enough. It will automatically print it out.

Comment: its not guaranteed to especially if the script is running silently

Comment: Haha yea I don't care. I was going to post if no one else had a PowerShell answer. But I forgot that `gc` was an alias and was just going to use `cat`, so you had a byte on me there anyway.

Comment: Uh, I wouldn't be that strict about it. Otherwise every PS answer would explicitly have to pipe to the host shell, but that's up to you...

Comment: You could instead use `gc $PSCommandPath` for 17 bytes. The problem I see is that this spits out a newline (which doesn't exist in the source). It's ambiguous now if trailing newline is OK or not ... depending upon how that rules, we may need to do something tricksy like `gc $PSCommandPath|write-host -n` for 31 bytes.

Comment: Also, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: hahaha yes not sure on the ruling on that, hopefully OP will answer that...thanks team!

Answer (score 7):

### C, 31 bytes

```
main(){system("cat "__FILE__);}
```

[The bash solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62143/3544) is so short, so why not base a C solution on it?

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 15 bytes

```
$><<IO.read($0)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474861/shortest-ruby-quine

Comment: I've converted this to a community wiki because it isn't your own work.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
$import sys$h'e$sys.argv
```

This reads its file name. Essentially, it looks up argv, opens the file corresponding to its last argument, and prints its first line.

Comment: Can't you just do `h'$__file__$`?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos That gives me the error `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`. Pyth is compiled to Python, and then the resultant string is executed. So I wouldn't expect that to work.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 16 bytes

```
FilePrint@$Input
```

Run it in [script mode](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html).

Comment: I've been using Mathematica for many years and had never even heard of script mode.

Answer (score 5):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 Bytes

```
0:0go:c=?;1+!
```

Tested both on the online and offline interpreters. The `g` command is the closest to being able to read from the source file and if it doesn't count for the purpose of this challenge I'll mark my entry non-competing; I do believe it normally considered "cheating" for quines.

[Try it online.](http://fishlanguage.com/playground)

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 63 bytes

For science!

```haskell
import System.Environment
main=getProgName>>=readFile>>=putStr
```

Comment: Only works with the `runhaskell` command. Very cool though

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 bytes

```hs
{-#LANGUAGE CPP#-}main=putStr=<<readFile __FILE__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1pX2cfRzz3U0d1VwTkgQFm3NjcxM8@2oLQkuKTI1samKDUxxS0zJ1UhPt7N08c1Pv7/fwA)

(GHC) Haskell has an extension to use the C preprocessor (commonly used for portability between versions and architectures.) Hopefully self-explanatory.

Answer (score 5):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```rust
fn main(){print!("{}",include_str!(file!()))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDqbpWSSczLzmnNCU1vrikSFEjLTMnVVFDU1Oz9v9/AA)

The file macro expands to the file it's invoked in's file path, the include_str macro expands to a string literal containing the contents of the file at the specified path, and the print macro prints.

Answer (score 4):

## Go, 133 Bytes

> Everyone clear? Go!

```
package main
import("fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"runtime")
func main(){_,f,_,_:=runtime.Caller(0)
s,_:=ioutil.ReadFile(f)
fmt.Print(string(s))}
```

Comment: This inspired me to write my own (and the very first) code-golf solution in Go. Looking for some general tricks, you can easily go down to 123 characters here by applying single-letter names for packages, for example `r"runtime"`.

Answer (score 4):

## , 2 chars / 6 bytes

```
ℹ⬮
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin//interpreter.html?eval=false&input=&code=%E2%84%B9%E2%AC%AE)</kbd>

The ℹ function both returns and pushes to the stack the source code. There is automatic outputting, so the contents of the stack will be outputted. Therefore, the source code will be outputted.

Comment: Does this read the source file, or a copy of the source code?

Comment: [Here's the line in the interpreter source with the function.](https://github.com/molarmanful/ESMin/blob/gh-pages/interpreter.js#L5) It's not really a file-based interpreter, but it reads the textarea value (aka the code).

Comment: You made [this change](https://github.com/molarmanful/ESMin/commit/ef4c98036bcc6f52ffa31aa8f777ea1ff93effee) an hour ago. Would your code have worked with the previous version?

Comment: @Dennis I actually made that change before seeing this challenge. It was because I didn't like the original output format.

Comment: @molarmanful Nevertheless, [according to site policy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5447/3808), this is a noncompeting answer due to the fact that it uses a version of your language created *after* the challenge was posted.

Comment: Alright, added disclaimer.

Answer (score 4):

## HTML with JavaScript, 115 bytes (doesn't really count)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><title>x</title><script>alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document))</script></html>
```

Does this count? I don't mind, it was fun :)

Technically it doesn't open a file. It's also a well-formed HTML5 document. The XMLSerializer was the only tool which also returned the DOCTYPE portion, but is non-standard. Still, it works on chrome and firefox, and I bet other browsers.

And as a bonus:

## JavaScript, 41 bytes

```
alert(document.currentScript.textContent)
```

Comment: Remove ";" at the end, save 1 byte :)

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков You're right, not sure why I left that in back then. It seems like I didn't count it though.

Comment: You don't need the `<title>x</title>`

Comment: @VFDan A well-formed standalone HTML document needs a title of at least one character, even if browsers will make do without it. I thought it was a nice bit of trivia to display in this silly answer.

Comment: Are `<head>` and `<body>` not needed for well-formed HTML?

Comment: @Somebody Nope. The head element implicitly begins when a tag that should be inside the head is encountered, and the body implicitly begins when a tag that is only allowed in the body and not the head is encountered. Even the html tags are optional, I guess I didn't know that in 2015. Though you should probably always put the opening html tag so you can specify a `lang` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

## Node.js, <s>66</s> 63 bytes

```
p=process;p.stdout.write(require('fs').readFileSync(p.argv[1]))
```

Doesn't use `console.log`, which appends a newline.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using the synchronous api: `p=process;p.stdout.write(require('fs').readFileSync(p.argv[1]))`

Comment: Why not `console.log(require('fs').readFileSync(process.argv[1]))\n` for 57 bytes?

Comment: This doesn't always work. Say the file is named `test.js`. It is valid to invoke it by running `node test`, which will cause this to throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>133</s> 125 Bytes (or <s>150</s> 142 slightly cleaner)

Based on @VoteToClose's answer but choosing Files.copy and thus avoiding the intermediate String creation needed to call System.out:

```
import java.nio.file.*;interface A{static void main(String[]a) throws Exception{Files.copy(Paths.get(A.class.getName()+".java"),System.out);}}
```

or hard-coding the class-name even more:

```
import java.nio.file.*;interface A{static void main(String[] a)throws Exception{Files.copy(Paths.get("A.java"),System.out);}}
```

Cleaned up:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

class A {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        Files.copy(Paths.get("A.java"), System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! (Programming Puzzles and Code Golf). Nice first answer!

Comment: This is _almost_ invalid, as we were told to not hardcode a filename.

Comment: You are not allowed to assume the file extension is `.java`.

Answer (score 3):

## F#, 54 Bytes

```
printf"%s"(System.IO.File.ReadAllText __SOURCE_FILE__)
```

Usage:

```
fsi --exec a.fsx
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, <strike>15</strike> 13 bytes

Credit to the Bash solution for inspiring this:

```
print`cat $0`
```

EDIT: Don't need the semi-colon or first space.

Comment: Not pure perl, it needs some other executable, namely `cat`, present and findable in the `$PATH`. But if it is present, it can be assumed as just a command available to `perl`, so why not.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala(2.10), 101 bytes

```
import scala.reflect.io.File;object A extends App{print(File(getClass.getName.head+".scala").slurp)}
```

Similar to the Java and C# answers.  The only "interesting" parts here are the `.head` to drop the `$` from the class name and the `slurp` method (which I'd never seen before) to read the file in as a String.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that method existed in scala. Mine is slightly longer using groovy.

Comment: You are not allowed to assume the file extension is `.scala`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 27 bytes

```
print next(open(__file__))
```

## Python 3, 28 bytes

```
print(next(open(__file__)))
```

Byte count includes new line.

Comment: My first contribution: harsh criticism welcomed.

Comment: Sad to see this one this far down while worse-scoring Python attempts are higher. As a historical note, this requires Python 2.6 and up; even 2.6 was past EOL at the time, but still.

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 17 bytes

```perl6
$?LANG.orig.print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1/F3sfRz10vvygzXa@gKDOv5P9/AA)

This relies on some compiler internals.

Answer (score 2):

### Java - <s>214</s> 194

```
import java.io.*;class Q{Q(){try{System.out.print(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getName()+".java")).readLine());}catch(Exception e){}}public static void main(String[]a){new Q();}}
```

Reduced a lot with using @VoteToClose method of finding the filename for java.

Readable version:

```
import java.io.*;

class Q {
        Q() {
                try {
                        System.out.print(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getName()+".java")).readLine());
                } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        public static void main(String[] a) {
                new Q();
        }
}
```

NOTE: The readable version doesn't actually work, it just reads the first line. Just to show what the code is doing

Comment: I posted a Java answer as one of the first answers. :P But, just in case you want to narrow this down more, you can remove `public` from the class declaration. Also, I might steal your method of getting a class name for my answer. ;)

Comment: You are not allowed to assume the file extension is `.java`.

Comment: @Makonede Are you sure? I get an error trying to compile anything that isn't `.java`

Comment: @Cruncher It doesn't matter, it's still specifying part of the file name.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 153 bytes

`class A{static void Main(){new A();}A([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath]string s=""){System.Console.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(s));}}`

Readable version:

```
class A
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new A();
    }

    A([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string s = "")
    {
        System.Console.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(s));
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Johnbot for the idea to use `CallerFilePathAttribute`, which avoids any kind of name hardcoding!

Comment: I _do_ smell elements of my answer in this! Well done! +1 And welcome to the community!

Comment: It's possible to get the source file name using the [CallerFilePathAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute.aspx).

Comment: You save 26 characters with `string s` instead of `string sourceFilePath`.

Comment: I think you can save another 8 bytes if you add `using System;` at the top and omit `System.` in all namespace qualifiers (at least I think it worked that way, it's been some years since I've worked with C#)

Comment: @Comintern - good catch, thanks. That's what I get for doing it in a hurry.

Comment: @hoffmale - that doesn't actually work. The `using` clause doesn't import sub-namespaces, just classes. So it would let me replace `System.Console` with just `Console`, but not `System.IO` with just `IO`. I could use an alias, `using S = System;` and shorten the uses of it, but that ends up being a wash.

Comment: ah, so that was only for classes... thanks for clarifying ^^

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (node.js), 65

```
with(process)require('fs').createReadStream(argv[1]).pipe(stdout)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 9 bytes

```
#!/bin/dd
```

Perl allows you to change the parser while the file's being read. One thing you can do is to change the program that parses the file entirely via the use of `#!` on the first line; this feature was intended to allow the use of Perl to fix a system on which shebangs didn't work correctly. `dd` with no parameters copies standard input to standard output (followed by some statistics on standard error which shouldn't matter), thus is a suitable program to use for a cheating-quine (because Perl reloads the file from disk to give to `dd`.)

Comment: That is not perl. The kernel reads the first two bytes and interprets them, finds `#!' and thus continues to read the line, finds `/bin/dd` and thus launches `/bin/dd`, given the file as argument to `dd`. NO PERL INVOLVED AT ALL.

Comment: @GolarRamblar: It is Perl. You can run `perl` followed by the filename, and *`perl` itself* will do the `#!` translation. It uses slightly different rules from the kernel for interpreting `#!` lines, in fact. (Perl originally added this feature so that if you were using an operating system, like Windows or DOS, that does not support `#!` lines, you could nonetheless use `#!` scripts by setting Perl as the interpreter for their file type.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), <s>28</s> <s>35</s> <s>32</s> <s>29</s> 21 bytes

```py
lambda:open(__file__)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZV6Kh8T8nMTcpJdEqvyA1TyM@Pi0zJzU@XvO/poamXlFqYoqGpk5qXoqturrmfwA) File objects are iterable, and output in a singleton iterable is allowed.

```py
lambda:open(__file__)  # full program
lambda:                # define function taking no arguments which returns...
       open(        )  # file at path...
            __file__   # current script path
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately as `print` will output a trailing newline not present in the original code.

Comment: You can suppress the newline by passing `end=''` parameter to `print`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI78gNU8jPj4tMyc1Pl5Tryg1MUVDUyc1L8VWXV3z/38A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Oh, I actually knew that but didn't know trailing newlines weren't allowed. I'll fix that.

Comment: This doesn't work. In order for the file I/O to be meaningful, the code has to be run from a file; while a function could be run at the interpreter prompt and its output would be displayed, a) it would display as a string representation and not formatted output; b) `__file__` would not be defined at the REPL and even if it were it couldn't name a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: The previous version, `print(*open(__file__),end='')` works fine and, unlike the competitors, doesn't require a trailing newline. However, that still doesn't beat Oddthinking's 28-byte (27 in 2.x) solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (Babel Node), <s>74</s> 72 bytes

Thanks to Kyle Slattery for posting his answer about `__filename`.

Also, thanks to Makonede for saving 2 bytes and making my answer correct.

```
require('fs').readFile(__filename,'utf8',(e,d)=>process.stdout.write(d))
```

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC! As noted previously, we require solutions to attempt to optimize for a challenge's scoring criterion; this is a [tag:code-golf] challenge so your code should be as short as you can make it. Some steps you could take might be to remove unnecessary whitespace (and semicolons? I do not actually know JS) and use shorter variable names. Also consider posting the score of your solution, and a link to an online interpreter (such as [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP11D3SM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFd8/9/AA)).

Comment: You should also check out our [Welcome Page](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange) to get a better idea of what we recommend and expect for answers.

Comment: thats what im going to do thank you

Comment: -2 by removing whitespace, removing braces, and renaming variables: `require('fs').readfile(__filename,'utf8',(e,d)=>process.stdout.write(d))`. Also, your answer is currently invalid, as it prints a trailing newline.

Comment: i missed that point, also thanks for your help man

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 22 bytes

```
input(*open(__file__))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhbbMvMKSks0tPILUvM04uPTMnNS4-M1NSGSUDUwtQA)

Comment: This requires the user to terminate the program (by hitting Enter and having the output discarded, or otherwise aborting it), but I tried it with shell redirection and it does get the right output, without adding an extra newline or anything.

Answer (score 2):

## Shell + `xargs`, 27 bytes

```
xargs -0a/proc/self/cmdline
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuha7KxKL0osVdA0S9QuK8pP1i1Nz0vSTc1NyMvNSISqgCmEaAA)

On Linux, the file `/proc/self/cmdline` contains the arguments provided to the current command, including the command's name itself, separated by null bytes. In this case, the command is `xargs`, and the argument is `-0a/proc/self/cmdline`.

`xargs -0` splits its input on null bytes, and passes them to another command. When a second command isn't specified, it defaults to `echo`. The `-a` option makes `xargs` read from a file instead of STDIN.

I'm not 100% sure if this is valid, because strictly speaking the source code of the shell script itself isn't in `/proc/self/cmdline`, but it certainly isn't a proper quine, so I think it morally ought to be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## [*nix interpreter directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), 10 bytes

```
#!/bin/cat
```

Shebang (`#!`) abuse. The shebang causes the "code" to be "interpreted" using `cat`, which prints out the content of the file.

EDIT: Someone else came up with it before me.

Comment: Some systems require a line terminator, eg. OpenBSD.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 56 bytes

```javascript
with(require('fs'))writeSync(1,readFileSync(__filename))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/PLMkQ6MotbA0syhVQz2tWF1Ts7wosyQ1uDIvWcNQpyg1McUtMwfCjY9PAzLzEnNTNTX//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

### VBScript, 67 bytes

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /K type "&Wscript.ScriptName
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (Win32), 36 bytes

```
main(){CopyFileA(__FILE__,"CON",0);}
```

CopyFile makes the challenge easier in Win32 than in POSIX or ISO C, that's for sure. You however need to call the compiler with stdcall as its default calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

### [Aubergine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Aubergine),  22 bytes,  noncompeting

The tab character at the end signals end of file, and the interpreters all crash without it. It's cool that this challenge showed up on my radar this week since I just finished golfing this for the wiki.

```
-a1+a1=oA=Bi-BA:bB=ia
```

I'll explain how it works later.  It does not use file I/O but it very much does read its listing, and it is definitely cheating.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy 92 bytes

Shorter than the other groovy answer, in addition to being filename agnostic.

```
print new Error().stackTrace*.fileName.collect{it?new File(it):null}.find{it?.exists()}.text
```

No newline at end of file.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 4 bytes

This language feature is newer than this question, but not made for this question.

```
iG`Z

i     Grab input. Since there is no input, it pushes -1 to the stack.
 G    Get the class name of the referenced class. -1 refers to the current class.
  `   Read the file under the name of the stack's contents and push all of it to the stack.
   Z  Output everything in the stack.
```

As of November 24, class commands allow for referencing other programs accessible by disk, or 'classes'. Normally, it'd be used something like this:

```
00k

;u someothervitsyfile
```

Where I execute the 0th line (the first line) of the 0th index of the uses list ('someothervitsyfile'). I can get its name with `G` like so:

```
0GZ

;u someothervitsyfile
```

And, if I have the name, I can get its contents like so:

```
0G`Z

;u someothervitsyfile
```

But the special cases of this are `-2` and `-1`, where `-2` references the superclass (as defined by ;e) and `-1` references the current class.

So, to get the name of the current class, I use `-1`, get its name, and, with its name being the only thing in the stack, I pull its contents with `.

Very fancy.

You cannot try this online, as it has been disabled to prevent reading server files.

Answer (score 1):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15), 8 bytes

Expects to be put in a file called `MOUSE.001`. (Files with the names MOUSE.nnn are the only files Mouse knows how to perform I/O on. I didn't write the interpreter.)

If the EOF char at the end of the file, which is printed to the terminal, crashes your terminal, it's not my fault and I consider this a feature, not a bug.

```
(1 &F!')
```

Additionally, technically this is undefined behaviour (though most of Mouse is *undefined* except in practice) because it promises that the file's length is at least as long as the `while(true)`. If this hangs your system because it's a loop, save your work, run `git commit && git push`, and don't say I didn't warn you.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 31 Bytes

```
print(io.open(arg[1]):read'*a')
```

The Arg table contains the following in lua.

{Filename, Command Line Argument1, Command Line Argument 2, ...}

Comment: That seems to be more like `{[-1]="Interpreter", [0]="Filename", [1]="Command Line Argument1, [2]="Command Line Argument 2"}`. So you should read `arg[0]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

### SmileBASIC, <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```
LOAD"PRG1:"+PRGNAME$(0),FALSE
PRGEDIT 1
FOR I=0 TO 3?PRGGET$();
NEXT
```

Load the program into slot 0 (the default slot), and run!

#### Explanation

```
LOAD"PRG1:"+PRGNAME$(0),FALSE  load the source code into program slot 1
PRGEDIT 1                      open program slot 1 for editing
FOR I=0 TO 3                   loop 3 times { (no newline here)
?PRGGET$();                      print line, supressing extra newline
NEXT                           }
```

The `,FALSE` on `LOAD` is required to supress a confirmation dialogue. I wasn't sure if this was required so I threw it in anyways (seems like it should be).

The extra setup of loading the source code into the neighbouring slot is required as SmileBASIC can't read or write from the currently loaded source code for some reason (it clearly reads it to load it into the other slot, but whatever).

As the output format isn't specified, you might be able to get away with just using the first line and claiming the output is found on slot one (which is one tap away) for 29 bytes.

Comment: `FALSE` in SB just means 0, because SB doesn't have a boolean type. Conditionals (`== != < > <= >= || &&`) evaluate to 0 when false and 1 when true (with the exception of `||` and `&&` which evaluate to 3 when the left term is a string; nobody knows why.) Any nonzero number is truthy, as well as all strings, even empty ones. NaN is always falsy and never equals itself. Arrays can't be compared though. Anyway, my point is, turn `FALSE` into `0` and save 4 characters. You could probably get away with allowing the loading screen but idk.

Comment: Thanks @snail'! That's exactly the kind of information I needed to get assimilated in golfing with SmileBASIC! I'll update my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 26 bytes (newline at end)

Saw @redstarcoder 's answer and wanted to out-golf it. I'm not sorry.

```
?LOAD("TXT:"+PRGNAME$());
```

This exploits the fact that PRG is just a resource subtype of TXT (it's literally the same file format with a different icon) and loads the source file into a string. It's then simply printed.

I removed unneeded whitespace wherever the parser would let me, and put it all on one line for show. `?` is just a shorthand for `PRINT`. The `;` at the end ensures the `PRINT` doesn't add an extra newline. This one also doesn't disable the load dialog popup, but whatever.

If you remove the newline using a program that deletes the last character (since SB automatically adds a LF whenever you save through the editor) you can also remove the semicolon, bringing the answer down to 24 bytes. I didn't do this though, because I consider it kinda underhanded.

Comment: Being "kinda underhanded" is probably ok in a challenge called "A 'cheating' quine"

Answer (score 1):

## Node.js, 63 bytes

Uses the [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename) global to obtain its file path as opposed to [`process.argv[1]`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv), which can be flawed:

```
require('fs').createReadStream(__filename).pipe(process.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GW-BASIC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC) / [Applesoft BASIC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applesoft_BASIC) / [IBM BASIC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_BASIC) / [Commodore BASIC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_BASIC),  6 bytes

```
1 LIST
```

Pretty simple. No matter where you loaded the program from or how much is in it, it will *always* print everything in the program buffer, including itself.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 44 bytes

```r
cat(scan(sub(".*=","",commandArgs()[4]),""))
```

Prints to `stderr` as well. If that's not allowed this works for 46 bytes:

```r
cat(readLines(sub(".*=","",commandArgs()[4])))
```

Run these from the command line using `Rscript`.

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque - 25 bytes

***With-IO***

```
,%____FILE?rfQ
```

**Disclaimer**: I've just added `____FILE` because I/O support is still very rudimentary and there was no way of detecting the name of the file. Otherwise this would have been impossible. I/O built-ins aren't available in default builds but can be activated by using `ghc ... -DHAVE_IO_UNSAFE ...`.

***Without-IO:***

```
,#Q2 SH ~- ",#Q" \/ .+ sh
```

*Explanation:* Burlesque is nasty.

**Actual explanation**: `#Q` looks at its own source code and pushes the code that is left in the "execution pipeline" onto the stack. In otherwords: `#Q` pushes all the code that is to the right to the stack. However, `#Q` does not look at ALL the source code just what is left in the "execution pipeline of the current execution context":

```
blsq ) 2ro{#Qj}m[
{1 {j} 2 {j}}
```

The `#Q` here is only able to see the `j` due to the execution context.

On a side-note: Burlesque has other modifiers that allow you to modify code such as for example `#q` which allows you to overwrite the remaining code in the execution pipeline of the current execution context:

```
blsq ) 3 4 {?*}#q?+
12
```

`{?*}#q` overwrites the `?+` with `?*`. With `#J` we can inject/delay a piece of code by appending it to the execution pipeline:

```
blsq ) 3 4 {J?*}#J?+
49
```

The `#J` here appends `J?*` to the `?+`.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure this satisfies "You must use file I/O to read the source code".

Comment: Oh, right. I should stop stopping prematurely while reading.

Comment: Meh. If it's allowed for APL to read code from "in-memory" then I can do that too ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```lisp
#lang racket
(display(file->string(find-system-path'run-file)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@f9fOScxL12hCMzj0kjJLC7ISazUSMvMSdW1Ky4pysxLB3LyUnSLK4tLUnN1CxJLMtSLSvN0QSo0NTX//wcA)

Pretty straightforward - just finds the current file, reads it, and prints it back out.

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (C/AST, *nix), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

<kbd>\t</kbd> represents a raw tab.

```php
O`"cat `tr '\0' '\t'</proc/$PPID/cmdline|cut -f3`"
```

Doesn't work in the golfed interpreter for some reason, so no TIO.

Abuses the shell command built-in `<backtick>` and the standardized command line args for Knight, which is `knight -f file.kn`

`/proc/$PPID/cmdline` obtains the `\0`-separated command line arguments of the parent process (which is the knight interpreter itself), `tr '\0' '\t'` replaces `\0` with `\t`, and `cut -f3` takes the third tab-delimited argument. Then, we just `cat` the file and output the result.

A similar result can be done using the `-e` flag, but that doesn't read the source file from the disk (unless you count the `cmdline` file)

-1 byte using a raw tab over `\t`

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 18 bytes

```
print1(readstr[1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWmwqKMvNKDDWKUhNTikuKog1jNSESUHmYOgA)

The function `readstr` reads every lines as strings form a file. When `readstr` takes no input, it reads the source file.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 47 (46?) bytes

```c
main(s){write(!!read(open(__FILE__,0),&s,47));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzcxM0@jWLO6vCizJFVDUbEoNTFFI78gNU8jPt7N08c1Pl7HQFNHrVjHxFxT07r2/38A)

This **will** corrupt the stack and segfault, but not before printing the correct output.

If executing in a terminal we can do 46 bytes printing to `stdin`:

```c
main(s){write(!read(open(__FILE__,0),&s,46));}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 18 Bytes

```
history|tail -c18
```

**Note:** *Technically* this is not allowed because it gets history from memory, and not from disk.

### Bytes:

```
echo 'history|tail -c18' > quine
wc -c quine
18 quine
```

18 bytes (including the newline)

### Explanation:

`history` gets the bash history from memory and `tail` grabs the last 18 characters. This is a more proper quine than `cat $0` and `#!/bin/cat` because it includes the newline.

`echo "$BASH_COMMAND"` can be used to do the same thing for an extra 1 character.

Comment: I like that one, but it fails to obey the rule to read it's source from disk.

Answer (score 0):

### Tcl, 37 bytes

```
chan copy [open [info script]] stdout
```

The older, more self explanatory version (43 bytes):

```
puts -nonewline [read [open [info script]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 59 characters

```lua
print(io.open(debug.getinfo(1,'S').source:sub(2)):read'*a')
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ lua quine.lua 
print(io.open(debug.getinfo(1,'S').source:sub(2)):read'*a')
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 93 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
main(){std::fstream f(__FILE__);std::cout<<f.rdbuf();}
```

I wanted to do a “pure” C++ version…and I have to say that it doesn't do too badly: it's down to 54 bytes if I can do without including the headers.

Comment: [78](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJimzpFi/uCQlWVtbL8OOKzcxM09DsxooYGWVVlxSlJqYq5CmER/v5unjGh@vaQ2WSM4vLbGxSdMrSkkqTdPQtK79/x8A)

Comment: [74](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJimzpFi/uCQlWVtbL8OOKzcxM09DsxooYGWVnF9aYmMDZqYVlxSlJuZqxMe7efq4xsdr6hWlJJWmaWha1/7/DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## A Groovy <s>103</s> 100 bytes!

<sub>Yes I know I'm evil</sub>

I stay in line with the other JVM answers (Java, Scala) to make this answer.

```
class X{static def main(String[]a){new X()}
def X(){print new File(getClass().name+'.groovy').text}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Emacs Lisp (93 Bytes)

```
:; emacs -Q -script $0; exit
(find-file (nth 2 command-line-args))
(message (buffer-string))
```

The first line calls the program in your normal shell and exits (to prevent the rest also being evaluated). `command-line-args` will be a list of three strings, `"emacs"`, `"-scriptload"` and the name of your file. `find-file` will open that file and make it the current buffer, so that `(message (buffer-string))` will write it to `stdout` as `-script` redirects messages there.

It should be noted, that `-Q` may not be necessary if your Emacs doesn't print other messages during startup, so that the first line could be shortened to `#!emacs -script`, shortening this to 81 bytes, but as it is highly unlikely that init and site-lisp files produce 0 messages at all, this cannot be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 8 bytes (non-competing)

APL does not use source files for single functions, rather a whole workspace (a machine-readable collection of token-representations) is saved and loaded, so I guess this is not allowed:

```
f     
⎕CR'f'
```

(`⎕CR` is Character Representation) as the program reads its current definition in memory (the loaded workspace), which may have been modified from the source in the file.

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 32 bytes

```
disp(fileread([mfilename,'.m']))
```

Comment: You are not allowed to assume the file extension is `.m`.

Comment: @Makonede MATLAB files have have the ending `.m`, so it would make sense doing anything other than that. The challenge specifically says we have to read the file *name*, not the ending, and OP actually confirmed that we can use the file ending.

Answer (score 0):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 11 bytes

```
program put
```

[Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html)

Outputs the program stored in the `program` variable. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

## HTML and Javascript, 88 Bytes

```
<head></head><body><svg onload="alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML)"></svg></body>
```

Had to add `<head></head><body></svg></body>` because that's what the browser outputs regardless of the original file.

Comment: #HTML and Javascript, 109 Bytes# <html><head></head><body onload="alert('<html>'+document.documentElement.innerHTML+'</html>')"></body></html>
@Masterzagh, Actually browsers add `html` tag too. Sorry, Couldn't add a comment as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I tested it on firefox and chrome and neither added the html (at least on the alert which is what we're interested in).  @prathapareddy

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to Jonathan Frech*

```lua
print(io.open(arg[0]):read())
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0QjM18vvyA1TyOxKD3aIFbTqig1MUVDU/P/fwA)

### How?

Lua uses the `arg` table to store it's arguments, the script name is always stored at index `0` of this table despite the fact there are no further arguments. After using this table to get the name of the file, printing it was as easy as opening the file and reading its content.

Comment: I think you can toss your variable and save three bytes.

Comment: It is interesting, how your script's file name is stored at 'index' zero, even though LUA is 1-indexed ... And it goes on: `arg[-1]` contains the language name ...

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg) / POSIX shell, 16 bytes

```perl6
run 'cat',$?FILE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@oNE9BPTmxRF1Hxd7N08f1/38A)

Answer (score 0):

### [CopyPasta Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CopyPasta_Language), 32 bytes

But I think this is interesting enough to compete here.

```
CopyFile
TheFuckingCode
Pasta!
```

Copy the source code, display the clipboard, and stop the program.

Comment: Worthy of note: This language did not have an interpreter when you posted this, so it would have been invalid. As of rn, I have [implemented an interpreter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CopyPasta_Language/implementation.rb) for the language, since the linked interpreter on the esolang is a dead link

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) `u`, 26 bytes

```
“open(sys.argv[2])”ŒV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5z8gtQ8jeLKYr3EovSyaKNYzUcNc49OCvv/HwA)

*Not* encoded in Jelly's SBCS, because 1. by meta consensus on flags Jelly `u` is a different language from Jelly (so it's not like I'm handicapping myself or anything), 2. I'm having some difficulties deciding on what form of output would be valid for an SBCS Jelly cheating quine, and 3. I'm having some difficulties [actually executing on the methods I've considered](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6CyJCM/z1jBxkbB1d@NK60oP1chKzUnp1IhM7cgv6hEITk/JTW@IDE9laugKD@9KDFXwVZB/VHDnBPbrY9MP7b0UeP2h7u7c80Ob4g/PP/Q5sMTVA8ve7iz7cT6wxOP7Nc5tPvopDCg/OEZXupc5ZklGQr5Bal5GupQo@LTMnNS1XXUy5PUNRUSixXSrLgU0vTKizJLUjWSKktSizXgtutl5qWkVmgkayqk5RcpJCtk5inA3JOZBuHD1WpqcoH8kpxYooBsEVdqckY@F8RzaSgy//8DAA) (note that that's not even shorter than this).

```
“open(sys.argv[2])”ŒV    Evaluate "open(sys.argv[2])" as Python, within Jelly's interpreter.py.

      sys.argv           Get the arguments with which this was invoked on the command line.
                         (jelly fu [whatever the file's called])
              [2]        Take the third argument,
 open(           )       and open the file at that location.

                   ŒV    Iterate through the file object, obtaining a Jelly string of its contents.
```

Comment: This can be encoded in the SBCS and be perfectly valid at the same time.

Comment: @Makonede It still presents the difficulty of taking SBCS-encoded file contents and outputting either the corresponding UTF-8 or the same bytes.

Comment: How about this: The output should look identical to the program. So the corresponding UTF-8.

Comment: ...I was about to say "well guess what I already tried", but it turns out the apparent failure is an issue with TIO's bash rather than the solution itself. Glad I tried that again

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>43</s> <s>39</s> <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```py
’ƒÛ(__£Ø__('Ë‚').Òœv[1])’.E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPMY5MOz9aIjz@0@PCM@HgN9cPdjxpmqWvqHZ50dHJZtGGsJlCJnuv//wA) I would've used the rewrite, if only I knew Elixir… Output doesn't contain the program, however it is the program in a singleton iterable object (a file). [This is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/94066).

```py
’ƒÛ(__£Ø__('Ë‚').Òœv[1])’.E  # full program
’ƒÛ(__£Ø__('Ë‚').Òœv[1])’    # push "open(__import__('sys').argv[1])"...
                         .E  # evaluated as Python code
                             # implicit output

============================================================================

open(__import__('sys').argv[1])  # full Python program
open(                         )  # return file at path...
                           [1]   # second...
     __import__('sys').argv      # command-line argument
```

**Note:** This program assumes no command-line flags or extra arguments are passed. If this assumption is not allowed, it can be fixed at a cost of 1 byte by adding a `-` before the `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```julia
print(readline(@__FILE__))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69Eoyg1MSUnMy9VwyE@3s3TxzU@XlPz/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## Processing, 48 bytes

```
print(loadStrings(getClass().getName()+".pde"));
```

Comment: I don't know Processing, but this looks like it wouldn't work if the file name didn't end in `.pde`.

Comment: The java answer sais , `getClass().getName()+".java"`  
Also I don't know if there is a way of getting the extension,
you can get a list of filenames in a folder but it's not bulletproof either

Answer (score 0):

## Nim, 43 bytes

```
import os
echo readFile(paramStr(0)&".nim")
```

Comment: See my comment on the above answer. You are not allowed to assume the filename ends in `.nim`.

Comment: @Makonede The Nim compiler won’t compile a file that does not end in `.nim`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ([Deno](https://deno.dev/)), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```javascript
console.log(Deno.readFileSync(import.meta.url))
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 31 bytes

```
main(){system("cat "__FILE__);}
```

Works perfectly...

Comment: [Duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62722/76323)

Comment: Whoops — didn't see that one or the Bash solution it was based on. First attempt was to use `exec(3)` but that didn't link properly. Great minds think alike, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```
stdout.write currentSourcePath.readFile
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY31YtLUvJLS_TKizJLUhWSS4uKUvNKgvNLi5JTAxJLMvSKUhNT3DJzUiHKobpgugE)