# Create and write to a file

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, hello-world, file-system

### Challenge

Create a new file and write the string `Hello World` to it.

### Restrictions

- Your challenge must write to a file on disk, in the file system.
- The file may not be a log file generated during normal operation of the interpreter.
- The file must contain **only** the string `Hello World`. It is allowed to contain a trailing newline or minimal whitespace. No other content.
- No command-line flags/pipes (etc) allowed, except when necessary to run the program. (e.g. `perl -p`)

### Notes

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program in bytes wins.
- Follow the spirit, not the letter, of the rules.

Comment: Is trailing newline okay?

Comment: @Winny yes, it is ok

Comment: Is a filename part of the contents of a file?

Comment: Could I also write to a magnetic tape, or must it be a disk? If so, are you including 3.5" and 5.25" disks? Or do you mean a "hard disk" or solid state disk?

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Those are acceptable too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pyth, 14 bytes

```
.w"Hello World
```

Outputs to a file called `o.txt`.

Answer (score 25):

## Python 2, 32 bytes

```
print>>open(*"ww"),"Hello World"
```

[Yes, this is valid python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0214/).

Comment: Woah. Explanation?

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan it looks like the main trick is how `*` can split an iterable into individual arguments in a function, so `open(*"ww")` becomes `open("w","w")`.

Comment: @ValueInk Actually the main trick is the use of the extended print statement which is rarely seen in the wild.

Comment: That is indeed a cool trick, but if it weren't for your `*"ww"` trick you'd've tied with the other Python answer here, which uses `open(...).write(...)` instead for the same byte count

Comment: Oops, I didn't even realise that.

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 25 bytes

```hs
writeFile"o""Hello World"
```

Answer (score 6):

### zsh, 17 bytes

```
<<<Hello\ World>x
```

Outputs to a file called `x`.

Comment: Can you interpreted the `>` as a pipe?

Comment: What about `>Hello\ World`

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal 2.5.3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.5.3), 32 bytes

```
kh→@|;@+open(*"ww").write(VAR_)#
```

Vyxal can't really do anything with external files, which would normally render this challenge impossible. However, in Vyxal 2.5.3 and prior, there was an ACE exploit allowing for arbitrary Python execution. [Yep, I found another one.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231059/101522)

---

##### The ACE:

Vyxal is a transpiled language, so every Vyxal command is translated to some Python code, and then all of the translated commands are executed. Previously, I found that you could escape a string to insert any Python commands you wanted into the transpiled code. It turns out that you can do something similar with function names.

When defining a function in Vyxal, the resulting python looks something like this:

```
def FN_func(parameter_stack, arity=None):
    ...setup stuff...
    ...commands...
    ...finishing stuff...
    return stack
```

When calling a function in Vyxal, the resulting Python code looks something like this:

```
stack += FN_func(stack)
```

The thing is, when parsing the name of a function, the strategy was to just read characters until reaching a `:`, `|`, or `;`, which are the delimiters of different parts of the function declaration/call. This meant that you could put any characters you wanted into the name, and it would attempt to transpile it the same way.

In this case, I used a `+` in the function name when I called it. That results in this transpiled code:

```
stack += FN_+open(*"ww").write(VAR_)#(stack)
```

This code will error when ran, because it tries to add together a function and the None that is returned from the `open` command. However, even though it errors, the `open` command still runs, meaning that we have executed arbitrary Python. If you wanted to write longer sections of Python code, you could replace the `+` with `([])` and add a newline after it.

---

##### The program:

In this program, the payload (the arbitrary Python code) is the following:

```
open(*"ww").write(VAR_)
```

The basis of this code is the `open().write()` command, which creates a file named `w` if it doesn't exist, then writes the contents of `VAR_` to it.

The `VAR_` variable is set at the beginning of the Vyxal program with `kh→`. This pushes the builtin `Hello World` and saves it to the nameless variable. All variable names are prepended with `VAR_` internally, so the variable `VAR_` is created and contains `Hello World`, which is written to the newly created file. Even though this has the overhead of the ACE setup, it ends up being shorter than the Python solutions due to the builtin.

This ACE has not been fixed in the repo, but it had a patch applied server-side for the online interpreter. It was also fixed in the rewrite and subsequent 2.6 release. If you want to try out this program for yourself, you can download the 2.5.3 version [here](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.5.3).

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, 15 + 2 == 17 bytes

```
iHello World<esc>ZZ
```

+2 bytes for launching this with `vim f` instead of `vim`. Additionally, this version works to:

```
iHello World<C-o>ZZ
```

If launching vim like this is not allowed, there is also:

#### Vim, 18 bytes

```
iHello World<esc>:w f<cr>
```

Side note: this is a polyglot. The same thing works in V, except that it is one byte shorter (since the `<cr>` at the end is implicit.)

Comment: What's the ` f<cr>` at the end for?

Comment: @Zwei 'f' is the name of the file, and the `<cr>` (which is a mnemonic for "enter", a single byte) is necessary to run the command. Commands that start with a colon are like a mini shell inside of vim, and the command `:w` is the command for writing to a file.

Comment: Should `<esc>` not be counted as 5 bytes and `<cr>` as 4, since they have to be fully typed in?

Comment: @BartvanNierop No, `<esc>` is just notation for "The escape key", which is `0x1B`, and `<cr>` is notation for "The Carriage Return key" which is `0x0B`

Comment: That's if you actually start vim and type it. As far as I'm aware, when you're writing the source code in vimscript, you have to type them out.

Comment: Well first off, there is a precedent to [score vim with keystrokes == bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8999/31716), but second off, there are several ways to write this in vim "code" without using the vim-key notation. For example, if you use `<C-v>` to insert a literal escape character and a literal carriage return, then you can assign all of these strokes to a macro, and run it that way. You could also do it in vimscript with `normal 'iHello World^[:w f^M` which is how vim *displays it*, not how you enter it. `^[` and `^M` are both one byte.

Comment: And so I learn something new (about vim) every day. =] Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 26 bytes

Writes to file `f`.

```
open(?f,?w)<<"Hello World"
```

Answer (score 5):

### Batch, 19 bytes

```
@echo Hello World>o
```

Comment: Not sure if it counts as wrong, but it outputs "Hello World" and a newline to the file, rather than simply "Hello World"

Comment: What is the '@' good for?

Comment: @PEAR It prevents the command from being echoed to STDOUT.

Comment: @brianush1 [It doesn't count as wrong, apparently.](/q/87192/87206#comment214276_87192)

Answer (score 5):

## **Batch, 18 bytes**

```
echo Hello World>f
```

Comment: I think you need an `@`, or re-title this as (console).

Comment: The `@` is not necessary.

Comment: Try saving it in a batch file and run it as such (not directly type the command). You will then see that you need the `@`, because the command is otherwise printed too. That means you have two options: 1) Delete this answer because it will be a dupe 2) Relabel as (console).

Answer (score 3):

## C, 44 bytes

```
main(){fputs("Hello World",fopen("o","w"));}
```

Comment: This will segfault on some systems without `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @StevenPenny As long as there's a system/compiler where it's guaranteed not to segfault, that's fine. Answers generally don't have to be portable.

Comment: @StevenPenny [And now it has.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/135242311c6c5ad8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 19 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
⎕NPUT⍨'Hello World'
```

Creates a file with the name and contents "Hello World".

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, 15 bytes

```
"Hello World">o
```

`>` redirects the string to a file called `o` in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

## Node.js, 42 bytes

```
require("fs").writeFile('o','Hello World')
```

i don't think this needs explanation

## Node.js REPL, 31 bytes

```
fs.writeFile('o','Hello World')
```

for some reason in repl you dont need to include `fs`

Comment: I don't think this works. In order for it to work, you'd need `require("fs").writeFile("o","Hello World")`. Otherwise, fs is not included.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ huh ok. works in REPL for some reason

Comment: I beat you with 1 byte :P

Answer (score 3):

### Bash, 18 bytes

```
echo Hello World>a
```

Answer (score 2):

## ed, 19 characters

```
i
Hello World
.
w o
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ed <<< $'i\nHello World\n.\nw o'
12

bash-4.3$ cat o
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
'Hello World'Z#
```

This creates a file called `inout` and writes the string to it.

Answer (score 2):

### K, 20 Bytes

```
    `:f 0:,"Hello World"
    `:f
```

Confirmation;

```
    mmm@chromozorz:~/q$ cat f.txt 
    Hello World
```

Comment: Since nobody said it yet, welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: OK. I also think that you have extra leading spaces though. I will edit the spaces out if you want (I don't know if they are intentionally placed, but I think it was unintentional.)

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>38</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
sink(" ");cat("Hello World");sink()
```

I like how the created file has no name ! It's just <s>`.txt`</s> anything, in fact !

**-2** bytes thanks to @PEAR remark !
**-1** bytes thanks to @BartvanNierop !

This code will produce a file with no name.

Comment: Is the '.txt' really necessary? File endings are just for the user. A single character might me enough.

Comment: I don't know R, but could you not shave off another byte, as by @PEAR's suggestion, by simply naming the file `"a"`?

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <del>93</del> <del>77</del> 76 bytes

<del>`using System.IO;namespace N{class C{static void M(){File.WriteAllText("f", "Hello World");}}}`</del>

<del>`class C{static void Main(){System.IO.File.WriteAllText("f", "Hello World");}}`</del>

```
class C{static void Main(){System.IO.File.WriteAllText("f","Hello World");}}
```

[See it work](http://ideone.com/eQ5VAY), with an exception for unauthorized file access.

### Changelog

#### Rev2

- Removed unnecessary namespace
- Changed function name to Main (because otherwise it won't be detected as main function)
- Removed `using` directive (thanks [Jean Lourenço](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57027/jean-louren%C3%A7o))

#### Rev3

- Removed space that sneaked in.

## C# (without boilerplate), 47 bytes

```
void M(){File.WriteAllText("f","Hello World");}
```

Comment: You can save some bytes by removing the using and appending it directly to the method: System.IO.File.WriteAllText[...]

Comment: @JeanLourenço Thanks. I had that originally and then changed it for reasons unknown.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 23 bytes

```
#(spit"x""Hello World")
```

Anonymous function which creates file called `x` and writes `Hello World` there.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 34 bytes

```python
open("h","w").write("Hello World")
```

Outputs to a file called `h`.

Answer (score 1):

## [APLX](http://www.dyalog.com/aplx.htm), 15 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
'Hello World'⍈1
```

Creates an APL component file containing just one component; the desired string. It can be read back with:

```apl
      'Hello World'⍇1
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 28 characters

```
\A=@write{o;Hello World}@end
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@write{o;Hello World}@end'

bash-4.3$ cat o
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>100</s> 95 bytes

```
void f()throws Exception{java.io.Writer p=new java.io.PrintWriter("x");p.print("Hello World");}
```

Or if you want to close the writer after using it (**101 bytes**):

```
void f()throws Exception{try(java.io.Writer p=new java.io.PrintWriter("x")){p.print("Hello World");}}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
class Main{
  static void f() throws Exception{
    try(java.io.Writer p = new java.io.PrintWriter("x")){
      p.print("Hello World");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    try{
      f();
    } catch(Exception ex){
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
java -jar Main.jar
```

Comment: Java is my favorite language but jesus christ it's hilarious how bad a golfing language it is haha

Comment: @AlanTuning Indeed. xD I work with Java at work, and it's fun to code-golf in Java. You will NEVER be able to win a code-golf challenge here using Java, but it's still fun to write the Java code as short as possible.

Comment: well, you can just `void f()throws Exception{new java.io.PrintWriter("x").print("Hello World");}`

Comment: `java.io.Writer p=new java.io.PrintWriter` saves you some more characters.

Comment: @cliffroot Hmm, I tried that initially, but it didn't seem to write anything to disk. Will try again tomorrow, currently I don't have an IDE and file I/O doesn't work in ideone.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen, it seems like if you do not close the stream the write operation is not guaranteed to take place anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 43 bytes

```rkt
(display"Hello World"(open-output-file"f"))
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>118</s> <s>112</s> 98 bytes

---

**Golfed**

```cs
void M(){var f=new FileInfo("_");var s=f.CreateText();s.Write("Hello World");s.Flush();s.Close();}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
public void M() {
    var f = new FileInfo( "_" );
    var s = f.CreateText();

    s.Write( "Hello World" );
    s.Flush();
    s.Close();
}
```

---

**Full explicit code**

```cs
using System.IO;

namespace N {
    class C {
        public void M() {
            // A file name is required
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo( "_" );
            
            // Obtain the Stream to later write on it
            StreamWriter s = f.CreateText();

            // Write 'Hello World' to the Stream
            s.Write( "Hello World" );
            
            // Flush it to the file
            s.Flush();
            
            // Close the Stream, for security and integrity reasons.
            s.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.2** - `-14 bytes` - Changed to `var`s. Shoutout to [Jean Lourenço](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57027/jean-louren%C3%A7o).
- **v1.1** -  `-6 bytes` - Simplified names.
- **v1.0** - `118 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

---

---

I'll leave a version down below that only uses the Console to write on th file. Just because I can.

---

### C# Console Version, 39 bytes

---

**Golfed**

```cs
void M(){Console.Write("Hello World");}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
public void M() {
    Console.Write("Hello World");
}
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
using System;

namespace N {
    class C {
        public void M() {
            // Write 'Hello World' to the output handler
            Console.Write("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**

```cs
<Exe. file name>.exe > FileToOutput.txt
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.0** - `39 bytes` - Initial solution.

Comment: You can use 'var' instead of FileInfo and StreamWriter to save some bytes

Comment: Right! Completely forgot the `var`s thing... Thanks @JeanLourenço

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```nim
"o".writeFile"Hello World"
```

Yes, Nim has a function in the `system` module for opening a file, writing a string to it, then closing it again.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 47 bytes

```
f=open("o","w");write(f,"Hello World");close(f)
```

I tried using `writedlm`, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 37 bytes

```
main(){system("echo Hello World>o");}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>27</s>  23 bytes

```perl6
'o'.IO.spurt: 'Hello World'
spurt 'o','Hello World'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [eacal](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/eacal), 26 bytes

```
write a string Hello World
```

This `write`s a `string` `Hello World` to file `a`, creating it if not present. Basically:

```
write <fileName> <exec>
```

and

```
string <params to convert to string>
```

Run the program as:

```
λ node eacal.js writeFile
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 21 bytes

```
'Hello World'1!:3<'o'
```

This writes to a file `o` in the current directory, or, if not called from a file, in your `j64-804` file. `1!:3` is the write foreign, and `<'o'` is the boxed filename (filenames need to be boxed). The LHS is the string to write.

Answer (score 1):

**Java**

```
public class H
{
    public static void main(String[] a)
        throws IOException
    {
        FileWriter o = new FileWriter("x");
        o.write("Hello World");
        o.close();
    }
}
```

Simple I/O with no exception handling.

**Corrected**

Corrected the original code to write the correct string (`Hello World`).

Comment: Your answer would have been shorter if you had actually wrote the correct string..

Comment: @SeanBean: Huh, force of habit, I guess, that I wrote `Hello, world`. I corrected the code.

Comment: @DavidRTribble You can change `public class H` to `class H` and `IOException` to `Exception`. This will save you 9 bytes. Also, you should include the `import java.io.*;`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 89 bytes

This code was tested in Chrome.  In other browsers, the element must be in the document for the click method to work.

```js
a=document.createElement("a");a.href="data:text/plain,Hello World";a.download=1;a.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTML, 83 bytes

This code was tested in Chrome.  It relies on the image failing to load, then it clicks itself, triggering the anchor tag which is a download link.

```html
<a href="data:text/plain,Hello World" download><img src onerror="this.click()"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Awk, <s>29</s> 27 characters

```awk
BEGIN{print"Hello World">1}
```

(No, not another output redirection. Just Awk's syntax is similar.)

Thanks to:

- [Pedro Maimere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99944/pedro-maimere) for suggesting to use integer for file name (-2 characters)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ awk 'BEGIN{print"Hello World">1}'

bash-4.3$ cat 1
Hello World
```

Comment: Substituting `"o"` for a lone number like `1` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: Thank you, @PedroMaimere.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 28 bytes

```
puts [open T w] Hello\ World
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), <sup><s>48 37 30</s></sup> 29 bytes

```javascript
open`data:text/t,Hello World`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z@/IDUvISWxJNGqJLWiRL9ExyM1JydfITy/KCcl4f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 20 bytes

```
write("Hello World")
```

This creates a file named "data" in the current directory and write "Hello World" in it.

Comment: Welcome to [Code Golf!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) Nice first answer!

Comment: @Fmbalbuena thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Bash script, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
echo Hello World>o
```

Save this as a file `write.sh` and run it: `bash o.sh

Comment: Why did you repost a deleted answer?

Comment: Surely the quotes are unnecessary?

Comment: You can save a byte by escaping the space instead of using quotes: `Hello\ World`

Comment: @MTCoster, why? `help echo` says: “Display the ARGs, separated by a single space character and followed by a newline, on the standard output.”

Comment: @manatwork You're absolutely right, I was unaware of this!

Comment: @Dennis It was downvoted due to rules being written incorrectly. The rules are now fixed and I wanted to repost that answer without the downvotes.

Comment: That's not a good reason. After the rules have been clarified, people can just retract their downvotes. Duplicate answers are automatically flagged for moderator attention. Also, your edit makes your answer identical to [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87561/12012).

Answer (score 0):

## [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/), <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
FileWrite(FileOpen("a",1),"Hello World")
```

**Explanation**

[FileOpen](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileOpen.htm) takes two parameters and returns the handle of the file. Mode must be 1 for writing (appending) text.

> FileOpen ( "filename" [, mode = 0] )

[FileWrite](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileWrite.htm) takes two parameters, a handle and the text to write

> FileWrite ( "filehandle/filename", "text/data" )

If a file does not exist, AutoIT will create it. Note that in my example it will not have any file extension associated (filename: a), but can still be opened with any text editor.

AutoIT is a Windows only scripting language.

[Script-Example.com](http://www.script-example.com/themen/AutoIT-Online-Compiler.php) has an online AutoIT compiler that can verify the solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Php, 38 bytes

`file_put_contents('a', 'Hello World');`

Comment: You can save 15 bytes by calling the [execution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php). `\`echo Hello\ World > a\``

Comment: Heh heh that's not really PHP anymore.

Comment: 36 bytes: `fputs(fopen('a','c'),'Hello World');`

Comment: @AlexHowansky You can do `fputs(fopen(a,c),'Hello World');` and save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 34 bytes

```
fputs(fopen(7,'c'),'Hello World');
```

Comment: @Lukabot I reverted your edit because it should have been a comment, and it is completely different enough to be its own answer (the same language can be used multiple times if the approach is different)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
".txt"~Export~"Hello World"
```

Comment: Like in the answer using R... isn't a single character enough for the file name?

Comment: @PEAR Mathematica can't infer the file format without a file extension.

Comment: Oh, ok... maybe something shorter encoded in the same way?... .c for example?

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 20 bytes

```
`echo Hello World>o`
```

Perl will execute anything in backticks (`) as a system command.

Answer (score 0):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 37 bytes

```
OUTP="Hello World" HERE[<here>+"\\a"]
```

simply writes Hello World to a file called "a"(not even a text file) in the script execution environment,

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 27 bytes

```
exec('echo Hello World>o');
```

## PHP, 20 bytes

```
`echo Hello World>o`
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 50 bytes

```
s=>System.IO.File.WriteAllText("f","Hello World");
```

An anonymous function that takes in an unused argument and outputs the file.

Alternatively and cheating slightly this one:

```
s=>System.IO.File.WriteAllText("f",s);
```

That takes in a string and works assuming the string contains the text: `Hello World`, for 38 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 69 bytes

Lauded for being incredibly expressive, it's not the best golfing language...

```
(with-open-file (f "f" :direction :output) (format f "Hello, world"))
```

[See it work](http://ideone.com/XGKXUc), with permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 28 characters

```groovy
new File("o")<<"Hello World"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ groovy -e 'new File("o")<<"Hello World"'

bash-4.3$ cat o
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sed, 20 characters

(19 characters code + 1 character dummy input.)

```
s/^/Hello World/
wo
```

Seems the side effect of also displaying the string to STDOUT after the file was created is not prohibited.

Requires dummy input to work as per [Are languages like sed exempt from “no input” rules?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5476/are-languages-like-sed-exempt-from-no-input-rules)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ sed $'s/^/Hello World/;wo' <<< ''
Hello World

bash-4.3$ cat o
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic, 39 bytes

```
OPEN"f"FOR OUTPUT AS#1
?#1,"Hello World
```

Opens a file named `f` (creating it if it doesn't exist, wiping it if it does) and gives it the file handle `#1`. Then prints (`?`) to file `#1` the string `Hello World` (with a trailing newline).

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
“ṠȷŀƤoĊịSAĊhJİⱮa¤XPṢḞɦ»ŒV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//4oCc4bmgyLfFgMakb8SK4buLU0HEimhKxLDisa5hwqRYUOG5ouG4nsmmwrvFklb//w)

Executes the Python code `open(*'aw').write('Hello World')`.