# Golf you an anagram for great good!

Tags: code-golf, random, quine, permutations

## The Task

In this challenge, your task is to write some code which outputs one of its anagrams chosen randomly with uniform distribution but it should never output itself.

---

### Elaboration

Given no input, your program should output any one of the anagrams of its source code. Your program should never output its own source as it is, i.e. it should never be a quine.

---

### Input

Your program must not take any input. However, if your language requires input as a necessity, you may assume that it will be given lowercase `a`. You must not use the input in any way, though.

---

### Output

Your program can output in any way except writing it to a variable. Writing to file, console, screen, etc. is allowed. Function `return` is allowed as well.

---

### Additional Rules

- Your program's source code must have at least 3 **chars** (not 3 bytes).
- Your program's source code must have at least 3 possible anagrams (excluding itself). For example, `aab` does not count as a valid submission as `aab` only has two anagrams other than `aab` (`baa` and `aba`).
- Your program must not produce any error.
- Your program should output its anagrams *exactly*.
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) and [Standard quine rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine) apply.

---

### Example

Suppose your program's source code is `abc`. It should randomly output any one of the following (with uniform distribution):

1. `acb`
2. `bca`
3. `bac`
4. `cba`
5. `cab`

And, it should never output `abc`.

---

### Winning Criterion

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins! In case of a tie, the solution which was posted earlier wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121868/its-anagram-quine-not-just-quine?rq=1).

Comment: Does it need to guarantee that it behaviors correctly, or just with probability 1?

Comment: @PyRulez _In this challenge, your task is to write some code which outputs one of its anagram chosen randomly with **uniform distribution**..._ (First sentence (below **The Task**))

Comment: @Arjun so is a 0% chance of failure fine?

Comment: @PyRulez Failure? The code is supposed to output one of it's anagram (except itself) chosen randomly with equal chances of any of its anagram being outputted. I don't know what you mean with "Failure".

Comment: @Arjun going into an infinite loop, for example. The top answer has a 0% of never outputting anything.

Comment: @PyRulez 0% chance of failure is not only fine but necessary!

Comment: @Arjun okay, because there are two types of 0% probability events: ones that never occur and those that [almost never](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely?wprov=sfla1) occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
“v0¡µṾ;ḢŒ!QḊX”v
```

Just to get things started; this is almost certainly beatable. This is basically just a combination of a universal quine constructor and a "pick a random permutation other than the input" function; the latter may be improvable, the former almost certainly is.

### Explanation

**Universal quine constructor**

```
“v0¡µṾ;Ḣ”v
“       ”v   Evaluate the following, given {itself} as argument:
 v0¡µ          No-op (which starts with "v")
     Ṿ         Escape string
      ;Ḣ       Append first character of {the argument}
```

This can be seen to be a quine if run by itself. It's also a proper quine by most definitions I know of; it doesn't read its own source (rather, it contains a literal that's "eval"ed, and is given a copy of itself as an argument), it can carry a payload (as seen here!), and the `v` outside the string literal is encoded by the `v` inside.

**Pick a random anagram**

```
Œ!QḊX
Œ!     All permutations
  Q    Discard duplicates
   Ḋ   Discard the first (i.e. the string itself)
    X  Choose random element
```

This is really inefficient on a string this long, so I haven't been able to test the program as a whole, but I've tested it on shorter strings and it appears to function correctly.

Comment: Why doesn't thins work on TIO?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It probably bypasses the 60s time limit.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right.

Comment: While you have it in your byte count your code misses the necessary `Q`. However I think you can change this "all permutations" method with [a "shuffle" one](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYU6ZwaGFh7Y@3LnP@uGORUDGrq5HjXsO7X/UMLfs//@vefm6yYnJGakA) using `Ẋ⁼¿`, saving a byte while also allowing it to work on TIO.

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 117 bytes

Surprisingly this solution is shorter than I expected. Shuffles source code, until it differs from the original.

-2 bytes, thanks to @mbomb007
-3 bytes, thanks to @Wondercricket

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LYw9DgIhEEb7PQWhGXDVA0jmBlTUNgTHLIa/DJusF7dGEq3el7x8b3RkKeWTaxbsy2Mi5lZ5PxmHMOV9Wlj7Cr8Bht4URAdj0S3HFhMJi@huFgGurxqL6j63RMqdExXltNZL41h2YWfg/x7jU@ol@LDRFw)

```
s=r"""from random import*;R='s=r\"""'+s+'\"""'+';exec s';L=R
while L==R:L=''.join(sample(R,len(R)))
print L""";exec s
```

This is one of the basic quines in python, that I've modified

```
s = r"print 's = r\"' + s + '\"' + '\nexec(s)'"
exec(s)
```

Generating anagram is done by random module

```
L=R
while L==R:L=''.join(sample(L,len(L)))
```

Where R contains sourcecode

```
s=...
R='s=r\"""'+s+'\"""'+'\nexec s'
```

Triple quotes were needed as I was forced to keep actual lineseparators in code. Anagrams will have 3 lines anyway.

Comment: `exec s` instead of `exec(s)`

Comment: Since a `str` is immutable, you can save a bytes by doing `L=R` and using `sample` on `L` rather than using  `shuffle` on the `list`. [repl.it](https://repl.it/INj8). The idea is taken from [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668312/shuffle-string-in-python/2668366#2668366)

Comment: @Wondercricket Sample returns list of characters, so comparing it's results with R will always returns False. But some rearranging helps, thank s for the idea!

Answer (score 4):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 17 bytes

```
{`"_~"+m!(a-mR}_~
```

This isn't going to finish any time soon, so no TIO link this time.

As a consolation, here is a 20 byte solution that does terminate very quickly:

```
{`"_~"+:S{mr_S=}h}_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@doBRfp6RtFVydWxQfbFubURtf9/8/AA)

#### Explanation

```
{`"_~"+   e# Standard quine framework, leaves a string equal to the source
          e# code on the stack.
  m!      e# Get all permutations. The first one will always be the original order.
  (a      e# Remove that copy of the source code and wrap it in a new list.
  -       e# Remove all copies of the source code from the list of permutations.
  mR      e# Pick a random permutation.
}_~
```

The 20 byte solution instead shuffles the source code until its different from the original.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>376</s> <s>428</s> <s>426</s> 428 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;class M{public static void main(String[]a){String s="import java.util.*;class M{public static void main(String[]a){String s=%c%s%1$c,x=s=s.format(s,34,s);for(List l=Arrays.asList(x.split(%1$c%1$c));x.equals(s);s=s.join(%1$c%1$c,l))Collections.shuffle(l);System.out.print(s);}}",x=s=s.format(s,34,s);for(List l=Arrays.asList(x.split(""));x.equals(s);s=s.join("",l))Collections.shuffle(l);System.out.print(s);}}
```

+52 and +2 bytes for two bug-fixes.. I wasn't checking (correctly) if the randomly generating String was equal to the original source-code. The chances of this are astronomical small considering the amount of characters involved, but I have to validate it regardless to comply to the challenge rules.

My first [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) answer in Java..
[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#rY4xSwQxEIX/SgguJLI3INotW4itV10pFmPMejlmN2tmcuxx3M@2XhPE0kKxGGYew3vvW8M4xyTqgEeELIHgunOEzGp7nvMLBadYUMo6xvCqRgyT2UkK09vTM9rz16m41/@U07iGm5sr1y499wxDTCOK4fb2rmXbFWkeA4ui/j4lPDEgV20W4JmCmGqtY223gH/PSGyKr0YdYqn8/rdk7UMk8k5CnBh4n4eBvCHb7U4sfoSYBeYCJdV/ueg/Amn9E4rWv4ZY148pbhy6vf8E)

You can remove both `Collections.shuffle(l)` and add `!` in front of both the `x.equals(s)` to verify that the output indeed equals the program:
[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#rY0xC8IwEIX/SgwWEikB0a10cNepozicsUokbWruWlpKf3tNEEcdxOF49@C9982mapwndocOVEvGqlWmLSCyw9i0Z2s0QwIK0jlzYRWYWhTkTX07nkCOr5dhzv@0k@gEk/VSp32OOaqr8xWQwHSzTVFmwYq9QWI233kPAyrA6EWvsLGGRKzGkzJb9Kp8tGBRhGLcurvAfAdSGyLFgFRWyrWkmsCnmJwm/iOb849Uzr/w5vkJ)

**Explanation:**

- The `String s` contains the unformatted source code.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together

And this part of the code is responsible for outputting a random anagram:

```java
// Strings `s` and `x` now both contain the source-code:
x=s=s.format(s,34,s);

// Create a list with the characters of this source-code-String and loop
for(List l=Arrays.asList(x.split(""));
    // as long as String `x` equals String `s`
    x.equals(s);
    // Shuffle the list, and set it to `s` in every iteration of the loop:
    s=s.join("",l))Collections.shuffle(l);
// End of loop (implicit / single-line body)

// And then print the random anagram to STDOUT:
System.out.print(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `D`, 14 bytes

```
`q‛:Ė+:Ṗ$o℅`:Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJEIiwiIiwiYHHigJs6xJYrOuG5liRv4oSFYDrEliIsIiIsIiJd)

For a version that doesn't require ~1.2TB of RAM:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `D`, 16 bytes

```
`q‛:Ė+D{|Þ℅~=`:Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJEIiwiIiwiYHHigJs6xJYrRHt8w57ihIV+PWA6xJYiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Both of these use a fairly generic quine structure combined with some "generate some permutation other than the input" code.

#### Generic quine structure

```
`        `:Ė # Evaluate the previous code on itself
 q.          # Uneval
     +       # Append
  ‛:Ė        # ":Ė"
      ...    # Apply some transformation
```

```
 Ṗ    # Get all permutations of the input
: $o  # Remove the original string
    ℅ # Choose a random element
```

```
 {      # While   
D |  ~= # The current string equals the input
   Þ℅   # Shuffle it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
"34çìDJœ¦.R"34çìDJœ¦.R
```

This creates a list that is too big for TIO, so the link uses a smaller string, but the idea is the same.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@UmJSsZGxyePnhNS5eRycfWqYX9P//17x83eTE5IxUAA)

```
"34çìDJœ¦.R"           # Push this string
            34ç        # Push "
               ì       # Prepend
                DJ     # Duplicate and join 
                  œ¦   # Push all permutations except the original
                    .R # Pick a random element
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 128 bytes

```
!function a(){b="!"+a+"()",c=b.split(""),c.sort(()=>Math.round(Math.random())-.5),c!=b.split("")?console.log(c.join("")):a()}();
```

Uses sort() returning random -1,0, or 1 to shuffle the output.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 72 bytes

```powershell
&($f={for(;$r-eq$o){$r=-join(($o="&(`$f={$f})")|% t*y|Random -c 72)}$r})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBDkAwEADArzTNanYlvbg4SD/hBYQ2CJYlEaFvr5jzbHx5OQY/z7Zj8SkZhOCewIIViPU7MD0gzk48rojAThts/gIhkqY3U2d@v3W79rwo26myoAgSKaUP)

This is a variation of the quine `` &($f={"&(`$f={$f})"}) ``

```powershell
&($f={for(;$r-eq$o){$r=-join(($o="&(`$f={$f})")|% t*y|Random -c 72)}$r})
                             ($o="&(`$f={$f})")                          # Stores the original quine in $o
                    $r=-join(                  |% t*y|Random -c 72)      # Shuffles the characters and store it in $r
      for(;$r-eq$o){                                               }$r   # Exit the while loop and print when the shuffled quine is not the same as the origin quine
&($f={                                                                }) # Quine structure, to create a function and run it automatically
```

[A 74 bytes recursive approach](https://tio.run/##FcrRCkAwFADQX1m61r2yR3naT3iVotlCuIyS2LdPzvPZ@LL@GOw8K8PexigRnH4kPuBDDo5qYGV3BK/VxOOKCKwTie2/wAVK6E3Fmd1v1a09L0IZURZETaAYPw)

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, <s>27</s> 96 bytes

```
i=`cat $0`&&e=`fold -w1 $0|shuf|tr -d '\n'`&&while [ "$e" = "$i" ]; do `$0`; exit; done&&echo $e
```

`fold` divides the code in lines, `shuf` shuffles the lines, and `tr` put the code back together

fixed the issue of it outputing itself, now it will never output itself

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoAgFAWv8hDJVVDr8CQVaPlDIRTKsIV3t99qeMNjNnv71oI2u82Qg@k60uZIp0NfRhb19s9R84XeQS1R8aH4cBJmCEkCmhEE1gkuwXBgAr0h/zMSx3afIKm1Dw)

Comment: Does it have chance to output the code itself, without changes?

Comment: It also seems to only shuffle the lines, so not all permutations are possible, in particular since the program only has a single line...

Comment: All permutations are possible, test it. I am fixing the problem of it maybe ouputing itself

Comment: That `$0` looks like a violation of “Your program must not take any input.”

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just the filename. Therefore, even if it wasn't input, this is a cheating quine :(

Comment: Does $0 count as an input? the user never input anything, as @CalculatorFeline says it is the filename which can be anithing, and wont affect the result or show in it. Why it is a cheating quine?

Comment: @DrnglVrgs, that is how the code that reads its own sourse is called [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)#.22Cheating.22_quines). We had [such challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62141/a-cheating-quine) too and we enjoyed it. But here the requirement not seems to ask for cheating quine.

Comment: One trick to shorten it anyway: `cat $0` → `<$0`.

Comment: Thank you @manatwork you are right, I had not read the part of the quine rules that says that it must not acess it own code